# Est-il préférable de répéter « amie » dans « Parmi toutes ses amies, je suis son amie la plus proche »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Parmi toutes ses amies, je suis son amie la plus proche.

Ou serait-ce mieux de faire appel à un pronom démonstratif, en l’occurence « celle »?

Parmi toutes ses amies, je suis

…celle la plus proche.

…celle qui est la plus proche (d’elle).

Selon vous, parmi toutes les tournures citées ci-dessus, laquelle serait à privilégier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personnellement, j’opterais pour « Parmi toutes ses amies, je suis la plus proche. » ou, encore plus naturellement, suivant la suggestion de @jlliagre en commentaire, « De toutes ses amies, je suis la plus proche. »

Comment: Ou mieux: ***De** toutes ses amies, je suis [...]*

Comment: @jlliagre Merci jilliagre pour ton commentaire. Quant à mes formulations, même si elles ne semblent pas « naturelles », penses-tu qu’elles seraient correctes d’un point de vue grammatical?

Comment: Je fais référence au segment de la phrase débutant après la virgule.

Comment: @Thérèse je ne saurais dire si elle est grammaticalement incorrecte, mais la formulation « celle la plus proche » ne me parait vraiment pas naturelle. La formulation « celle qui est la plus proche » me parait parfaitement correcte, quoiqu’un peu lourde.

Comment: @user2233709 Merci user2233709!